# Hide element on select option

Tags: html, select, ionic-framework

I have an ion-select, and want to hide a part of it when I select an option

```
  <ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selectedUser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user._id">{{ getUserNickname(user) }}
      <ion-content >
        <a *ngIf="user?.isConnected">Connected</a>
        <a *ngIf="!user?.isConnected">Disconnected</a>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

I want to hide this when the option is selected

```
 <ion-content >
    <a *ngIf="user?.isConnected">Connected</a>
    <a *ngIf="!user?.isConnected">Disconnected</a>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: What are key and values present for users array?

Comment: isConnected & id & emails ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selectedUser._id" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)">
    <ion-option (click) = "changeSelected(user._id)" *ngFor="let user of users[value]="user._id">getUserNickname(user) }}
    <ion-content *ngIf = "(user._id == selected)">
        <a *ngIf="user?.isConnected">Connected</a>
        <a *ngIf="!user?.isConnected">Disconnected</a>
     </ion-content>
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

and in .ts:

```
changeSelected(data){
this.selected = data;
}
```

Comment: When doing this it will hide all the content unfortunately. no when selected

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question, hope edited logic helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id as only one value, use complete object and then check variable which is binded(ngModel). Like below:

```
<ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="selectedUser" (ngModelChange)="selectUser($event)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{ getUserNickname(user) }}
    </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Check binded value for show/hide content:

```
<ion-content >
    <a *ngIf="selectedUser?.isConnected">Connected</a>
    <a *ngIf="!selectedUser?.isConnected">Disconnected</a>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Not working i want only to hide the ion-content when i select the item